# Expected Number of Trials, No Replacement

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

Suppose there are $N$ marbles in an urn. $K \ll N$ of those marbles are red, the rest are black. How can I determine the expected number of draws *without replacement* before I draw a red marble?

I think this is related to a hyper-geometric distribution, but I'm not sure how to rearrange the formula to get what I need.

I've also identified that the result I want can be given by the recurrence
$$  g(n) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n \leq K \\
      \frac{K}{n}\cdot 1 + (1 - \frac{K}{n}) \cdot g(n - 1) & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$
evaluated at $N$. Unfortunately, I need a closed form, if one exists.

Thanks!

Comment: $K/n(1)$ doesn't seem to make sense -- is there a typo there?

Comment: I just meant $(K/n)(1)$ to make it a little more clear how I got that term, but I edited the post.

Comment: For that purpose, I'd suggest $(K/n)\cdot1$.

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Comment: I believe to make this work as a recurrence relation, you will want: $$g(n) = \begin{cases}1, & n\le K \\ \dfrac{K}{n}\cdot 1 + \left(1-\dfrac{K}{n}\right)\big(1+g(n-1)\big), & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Of course this can be simplified to: $$g(n) = \begin{cases}1, & n\le K \\1+ \left(1- \dfrac{K}{n}\right)g(n-1), & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ And now when you expand this, you get: $$1+\dfrac{n-K}{n}\left(1+\dfrac{n-K-1}{n-1}\left(1+\dfrac{n-K-2}{n-2}\left(\cdots \right)\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that you get $k$ black marbles followed by a red marble is:

$$\dfrac{(N-K)(N-K-1)\cdots (N-K-k+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots (N-k+1)}\cdot \dfrac{K}{N-k}$$

Rewriting in terms of factorials, we have:

$$\dfrac{\tfrac{(N-K)!}{(N-K-k)!}}{\tfrac{N!}{(N-k)!}}\cdot \dfrac{K}{N-k} = \dfrac{(N-K)!(N-k-1)!}{N!(N-K-k)!}\cdot K$$

Since this occurs after $k+1$ draws of marbles, and each outcome is mutually exclusive (you cannot get the first red marble on draws $k_1$ and $k_2$ unless $k_1=k_2$), you can write:

$$g(N) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-K}(k+1)\cdot K\cdot \dfrac{(N-K)!(N-k-1)!}{N!(N-K-k)!}$$

According to Wolframalpha, a closed form appears to be:

$$g(N) = \dfrac{N+1}{K+1}$$

Comment: I think that works! Thank you!